# Code Folding Issue in User Defined Language (NETLOGO) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, netlogo, folding

I have seen questions regarding creating folding in notepad++. I have found a Userdefined language where some folding is happening for netlogo, but I am running into the following issues:

1. It is folding where it sees an "if". I have looked in the user defining interface and the only thing showing is the "to"and "to-report" no "if". Why could it be trying to fold there? This results in the fold block never terminating rendering the folding functionality useless.
2. With "to" and "end" respectively creating and terminating folding blocks, I am having an issue when I call a different subroutine that has the word "to" in it like "move-to". Is there a way that I can limit it from starting blocks with to's preceded by a "-"?

Any help with these issues would be much appreciated! If somebody else has a better UDL for Netlogo in sublime or notepad++ PLEASE let me know, and if someone knows how to add the autocomplete functionality in a UDL (like closing a ( or [ or following a "to" with an "end" that would also be a great added benefit!

Thanks!

Comment: "I have found a Userdefined language" — link, please?

Comment: Honestly, I can no longer find the link. There was a list (on sourceforge I think) but when I try to navigate to the list now, it just takes me to the notepad++ sourceforge page. I can send you the file or something to that effevt, but I don't really know how or ever have posted things like that on public sites.. unless stackoverflow has that type of capability.

Comment: Is the thing you're using listed at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/resources.shtml ? Although it's conceivable that Notepad++ or Sublime modes for NetLogo exist that aren't listed on that page, it's unlikely. (Haven't used these editors myself so I can't address your question directly.)

Comment: Perhaps this will help find someone who can help: https://twitter.com/netlogo/status/481826568193323010

Comment: The language I'm using is a Notepad++ language, and I didn't see any support listed for that editor on the page. I should be able to dig up the language file if you would like to use it yourself. I wouldn't know who to contact to add it to the netlogo page, but it could be valuable for users of Notepad++.

Comment: And thank you I hope the twitter post will!